# How should I have a variable new link depending on a dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a dropdown that I want to be able to change which id to pass to a path.

**Dropdown**

```
<select id="student-selection">
    <option value="1">Frank</option>
    <option value="2">Bill</option>
</select>
```

**Link**

```
<%= link_to "Create Pet", new_student_pet_path(:id_from_select_dropdown) %>
```

How is this possible? I'm guessing that I should use coffeescript in some way but I can't figure out a good way besides just parsing the link string and replacing an ID.

I'm also willing to use a div with onclick event if that would make it easier instead of an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a good way of doing it. I just put the URLs in the select options as the values instead of using the IDs via the path functions. This way in the coffeescript I just need to set the window.location to the value of the selected option.

**HTML**

```
<select id="student-selection">
  <option value="/students/1/pets/new">Frank</option>
  <option value="/students/2/pets/new">Bill</option>
</select>
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
$ ->
  $('btn-id').click ->
    window.location = $('#student-selection').children("option").filter(":selected").val()
```